# Why is Tomcat not closing HTTP connections?

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat7

I recently installed an application on Tomcat 7. After a few days it stops responding. I have seen on Tomcat that there are some http connections do not time out even if they are closed is set to 20.000ms .
Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The connection timeoue only applies when Tomcat is waiting for data from the client. If Tomcat is waiting for the application to write data it will wait indefinitely.

You should take a series of 3 thread dumps, roughly 15s apart, to try and see what is goin on. I suspect you'll find some long running application code.

Comment: tnk for response! yes there is a long running application code but how i can kill this connection?